# convert float to vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point, uint8t

In a method like this:

```
vector<uint8_t> Transaction::bytes() {
  vector<uint8_t> result;
  ...
  return result;
}
```

I need convert a `float` variable to a `vector<uint8_t>` (where each byte of the `float` should be an element of the vector), to allow me add this vector to another:

```
  vector<uint8_t> temp;
  result.insert(result.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

Anyone can give a hint of how to do that?

Comment: `result.resize(sizeof(float)); std::memcpy(result.data(), &dasFloat, sizeof(dasFloat));`

Comment: That depends, what do you mean by "add"? You're probably going to want to do arithmetic with the actual float values.

Comment: When I see `dasFloat` I am struck with visions of a tense game of cat and mouse as bits try to slip through the Strait of Gibraltar in an encrypted tunnel while hunted by British anti-virus.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I mean, insert the vector generated from the `float` variable to the end of the result vector.

Comment: @SergeyA 1) Can I use `result,insert` instead of `result.resize`? 2) Is there any alternative to the use of `memcpy` ?

Comment: In C++, `std::memcpy` is the normal mechanism for moving bytes around between disparate types of objects.

Comment: For serialization, you could just use a stream class. For memcpy you're going to want & and sizeof

Comment: @user4581301 Looks like I succeed ;)